# unable to get static file like png,jpg in android through iis server

Tags: android, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

The DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest method is not supported by IIS integrated pipeline mode..But when i change to classic mode then iam able to get static file from iis but then at the same time my android application gives me 500:Internal server error..what i did wrong

Comment: Show some code ?

Comment: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: The DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest method is not supported by IIS integrated pipeline mode.... iam using retrofit for getting data from sql server...but when i change to classic i can access image file on web but at the same time android app connectivity issues

Comment: Please edit your question and put your error log there to have your question answered quicker.

Comment: [PlatformNotSupportedException: The DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest method is not supported by IIS integrated pipeline mode.]
   System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +4465216
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +1020
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +195
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +128